# The difference between two declarations of deleted function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this class widget:

```
class widget_11 {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void process_pointer(T* ptr)
    {
        std::cout << *ptr;
    }
    
};
```

my issue is that I don't understand whats the difference between
these two declarations:

```
 template<>
 void widget_11::process_pointer(double*) = delete;
 template<>
 void widget_11::process_pointer<double>(double*) = delete;
```

My question is if these two definitions of deleted functions do the same thing?
From my  testing they both compile and didn't change how code works, but maybe I skipped something important while testing

Comment: They achieve the same effect.   The second is more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those are declarations and definitions for an explicit specialization of `process_pointer` for `T = double` so they would define the same thing the same way.

When you write out the declaration for an explicit specialization, [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Explicit_instantiation) can be used to fill in types not specified. In the case of your first declaration, `T` is deduced as `double` from `T* = double*`. In the case of your second declaration, `T` is explicitly specified as `double`, and no template argument deduction is done.

There is also a third equivalent declaration:

```cpp
template<>
void widget_11::process_pointer<>(double*) = delete;
//  T needs to be deduced here ^^
```

And these empty angle brackets can just be omitted, leading to your first declaration.